# SqlNullValueException when performing DbGeometry Contains operation

Tags: c#

I am getting an odd exception when trying to do a `Contains` operation, i.e. is one instance inside another. There's no results on google for this exception, and both geometry instances are not null, and valid.

```
var inside = gridShape.Shape_MGA.Contains(shape.shapeMga)

Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean.get_Value()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlTypesAssembly.SqlBooleanToBoolean(Object sqlBooleanValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialServices.Contains(DbGeometry geometryValue, DbGeometry otherGeometry)
   at System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry.Contains(DbGeometry other)
   at ReprojectShapes.Program.ConvertSourceShapesToLocalGrid(String geoConnStr, List`1 shapesToReproject) in C:\dev\geology-workbench\WorkbenchService\Reproject
Shapes\Program.cs:line 152
   at ReprojectShapes.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev\geology-workbench\WorkbenchService\ReprojectShapes\Program.cs:line 33
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be that the SRID of the two instances are different!

One was created in a naive manner:

```
shape.shapeMga = DbGeometry.FromText(sourceShape1.shapeWkt);
```

And the other in a more "correct" way:

```
gridShape.Shape_MGA = DbGeometry.FromText(gridExtentsWkt, 28350);
```